# Insert text with drop down into DB

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I have table in database that has 3 column, the first column id(PK), second column nameOfPerson and third column parent(foriegn key). When I entered name into text field and choose parent from drop down I want to insert into the DB the name under nameOfPerson and parent under parent. Why in my code when I clicked submit nothing happens?

This is my table

```
id  nameOfPerson    parent
3   John             NULL
4   Michel            3
5   Husam             4
6   Khalaf            5
7   Mark              5
----------------------------
```

this is my function to get the who can be parent

```
    public function displayParent(){
     //$statment = $this->db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT  person.nameOfPerson, b.nameOfPerson as name FROM person LEFT JOIN person b ON (person.parent = b.id)");
        $statment = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, nameOfPerson FROM person");
        $statment->execute();
        $result = $statment->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $output){
            echo "<option>" .$output['nameOfPerson']."</option>";
        }
 }
```

this is my function to insert data into DB

```
    public function enterChild(){

        $statment = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO person (nameOfPerson, parent) VALUES(:name, :parent)");
        $statment->bindParam(':name',$_POST['name']);
        $statment->bindParam(':parent',$_POST['parent']);
        $statment->execute();
        $result = $statment->rowCount();
        if($result == "1")
        {
            $message = '<label>successfully</label>';
        }
            else
            {
                $message = '<label>Wrong</label>';
            }
    echo $message;
 }
```

and this is mu index code

```
<?php include_once('Family.php');
$object = new Family();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Family Tree</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  Child Name: <input type ='text' name ='name' placeholder="Enter name here">
  <select name="parent" id="names" onchange="getSelectValue()">
  <option>--Select Parent--</option>
  <?php echo $object->displayParent() ?>
  </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</form>

<script>
    //Get selected nema
    function getSelectValue(){

        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("names").value;
        console.log(selectedValue);
    }
</script>

<?php
    $object->GetFamilyTree();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name=  $_POST["name"];
        $parent= $_POST["parent"];
        $object->enterChild();
    }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any of the messages from your `enterChild()` method? Have you done any debugging? Checked the values in different stages in your code to see what you get and if the method is called etc?

Comment: You should also add some proper error handling for your query: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: yes he get the method and echo Wrong @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Then add error handling (my second link) to find out if the query fails for some reason.

Comment: he give me this error: PDOStatement::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: 'Husam' for column 'parent' at row 1 ) Wrong @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Then do a `var_dump($_POST)` and check what you're actually getting and are trying to insert. This is why you always should validate your inputs. Can you also edit your question to include the generated code from the `$object->displayParent()` method?

Comment: array(3) { ["name"]=> &string(4) "Test" ["parent"]=> &string(7) "Husam" ["submit"]=> string(5) "Enter" } Wrong

Comment: i update my code please check it @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Now its work ... thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails since the column `parent` needs to be an interger while you're sending in a string.

The issue is how you're outputting the selectbox for the parents.

```
echo "<option>" .$output['nameOfPerson']."</option>";
```

If you omit the `value`-attribute, the text (in this case, the name) will be sent instead.

Add the `id` as value and it should work:

```
echo "<option value='{$outout['id']}'>" .$output['nameOfPerson']."</option>";
```

Now the id will be sent instead of the name.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Magnus